# DAX Value sum for intersection

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm working in power bi. And I have a table with three fields: 'Date' indicating the data date, 'Value' representing the product's value, and 'ID_product' indicating the product ID.

I aim to calculate the sum of values for products falling within the maximum date and the day before – essentially, the intersection between these two dates (green area).

[image]

I attempted this with the following code, but the results are unsatisfactory. How can I modify it to achieve the desired outcome?

```
Suma_Interseccion =

CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        INTERSECT(
            VALUES(CDT[Documento]),
            VALUES(
                FILTER(
                    CDT,
                    CDT[CORTE] = MAX(CDT[CORTE]) || CDT[CORTE] = MAX(CDT[CORTE]) - 1
                )
            )
        ),
        CDT[Suma_Valor]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Saldo_Intersección = 
  CALCULATE( 
    SUMX( 
      INTERSECT( 
        CALCULATETABLE( 
          VALUES(CDT[IdProducto]), 
          FILTER(CDT, CDT[CORTE] = MAX(CDT[CORTE])) 
        ), 
        CALCULATETABLE( 
          VALUES(CDT[IdProducto]), 
          FILTER(CDT, CDT[CORTE] = MAX(CDT[CORTE]) - 1) ) 
        ), 
        CDT[Medida] 
      ) 
    )
  )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).